# Stale Code Coverge Files in Xcode

Tags: xcode4, code-coverage

So I was updating some unit tests and looking at the coverage (`.gcda` and `.gcno`) files in my `Derived Data` folder and all the files are there, but I noticed when I make an update to my tests and re-run them that the coverage files don't update.

I noticed this by looking at the timestamp on the files.

In the past I swear I could just make a change, re-run and the files would then update. However now I need to clean first then run my tests to clear out the old coverage files before re-running.

Has anyone else seen this behavior and if so, know how to fix it?

I'm using 4.6 with the iOS 6.1 SDK.

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to note from what I've seen. if you do clean and then run your unit tests via `ctrl+command+U` (Test Without Building) even if you build manually beforehand you'll get `.gcno` files but not `.gcda` files. You have to clean then do a full build and test (`command+U`)